How do I need write periodic timer to test connection to the server using Mobx?
I want to write the ReactionBuilder with Mobx, which will check a connection with my server periodicly and do new request to connect it if there is not a connection. How can I do it correctly?
I have the next state class of a page which contains a function to test connection with my backend server:
abstract class LandingPageStateBase with Store {
  final IempServerRepositoryBase _iempServerRepository;
  var counterTryToConnect = 0;

  ...

  @observable
  bool isLoading = false;

  ...

  @action
  Future<void> getTestConnection() async {
    counterTryToConnect += 1;
    isLoading = true;
    connection = null;

    try {
      final data = await _iempServerRepository.getConnection();
      connection = data;
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      connection = null;
    }

    isLoading = false;
  }

  bool isConnected() {
    return connection != null && !isLoading;
  }
}

And a part of widget page:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: SafeArea(
      child: ReactionBuilder(
        builder: (context) {
          _landingPageState.getTestConnection();
          // HERE I NEED TO CHECK CONNECTION AND DO IT AGAIN IF NOT CONNECTED
          return reaction((_) => _landingPageState.isLoading, (_) {
            if (!_landingPageState.isConnected() &&
                _landingPageState.counterTryToConnect < 4) {
              _landingPageState.getTestConnection();
            } else if (_landingPageState.isConnected()) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LogInPage()));
                });
              });
            }

            debugPrint('debug: ${_landingPageState.counterTryToConnect}');
          }, delay: 1000);
        },
    ...

I don't consider options using Stream, because I use the concept of working with Mobx and do not want to mix different approaches with reactivity. I just wanna understand how I can do it with Mobx.

I solved the problem the next way:
abstract class LandingPageStateBase with Store {
  final IempServerRepositoryBase _iempServerRepository;

  LandingPageStateBase(this._iempServerRepository);

  final _maxRetryToConnectCount = 10;
  int retryToConnectCount = 0;

  Connection? connection;

  @observable
  ConnectionState connectionState = ConnectionState.waiting;

  @action
  Future<void> connectToServer() async {
    connectionState = ConnectionState.waiting;

    try {
      final data = await _iempServerRepository.getConnection();
      connection = data;
      connectionState = ConnectionState.done;
    } catch (_) {}

    if (connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      retryToConnectCount = 0;
    } else {
      retryToConnectCount++;

      if (retryToConnectCount < _maxRetryToConnectCount) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        connectToServer();
      } else {
        connectionState = ConnectionState.none;
      }
    }
  }
}

And the page's widget:
child: ReactionBuilder(
        builder: (context) {
          _landingPageState.connectToServer();
          return reaction((_) => _landingPageState.connectionState, (_) {
            if (_landingPageState.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LogInPage()));
                });
              });
            }
            debugPrint('debug: ${_landingPageState.connectionState.name}');
          }, delay: 2000);
        },

